# How to only get DISTINCT rows from a JOIN query: MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables. Table one is users. Table two is user events. One user has many events. I just want to get a list of the users with the most recent events. I can obviously set it to select more rows than I need and filter out the duplicates but I really want to just select the exact number of rows I need in the SQL.

This SQL query gives duplicates of `a.name` where one user has had more than one event recently. I thought that `DISTINCT` would prevent duplicates. What am I doing wrong? How do I just get one row for each user?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.name), b.date , a.id
FROM `users` a
INNER JOIN events b
ON a.id = b.userid 
WHERE now() > b.date 
ORDER BY b.date DESC, a.id DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Table users...

```
id name
```

Table events...

```
id userid date
```

I don't need to select the `b.date` value but this is needed for `DISTINCT` to work because it is in the `ORDER BY` part, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `GROUP BY` the user and only take the maximum `date` (or the minimum, if you want the oldest of the events).

```
SELECT a.name,
       max(b.date) date,
       a.id
       FROM users a
            INNER JOIN events b
                       ON a.id = b.userid 
       WHERE now() > b.date 
       GROUP BY a.id,
                a.name
       ORDER BY max(b.date) DESC,
                a.id DESC
       LIMIT 30;
```

`DISTINCT` won't help you, when there are different `date` values for a user. Those records are distinct because of the different `date` values, though sharing a user.

Comment: Perfect, I will accept this answer as soon as I can. Thank you very much. This way does not need the date to be selected, which is also good.